# How to test for valid file name in Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, validation, file

Anyone know how to test if a string is a valid file name in Mac OS X, other than trying to create file with that name?

The issue I'm having is that sometimes, a file name can be too large. OSX has a byte limit for filenames and with unicode characters you can't just check the length of the string since they can be more than 1 byte.

Comment: Moreover, the string could have an invalid Unicode character sequence (e.g., a broken surrogate pair) or a slash.

Comment: A lot depends on the filesystem you're writing to. In particular I believe many network file systems can't tell you what's valid until you actually try it.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac OS X, a file is nothing more than a resource; and the path/filename is the location.  Create an **NSURL** object using [+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The method will only return a valid object if the filename is valid.

Excerpt from Apple Docs:

- **NSURL** objects can be used to refer to files, and are the preferred way to do so.
- The **NSURL** class will fail to create a new NSURL object if the path being passed is not well-formed—the path must comply with RFC 2396.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSFileManager.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3A)

-- Updated:

Try this:

```
if([testPath compare: [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[testPath fileSystemRepresentation]]] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //testPath is a valid Path
}
```

No guarantees on what it will do though.

Comment: I need to know if a file name is valid, not if the file already exists.

Comment: Try this `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myPath fileSystemRepresentation]];`

Comment: I've tried this with an arbitrary sentence from a book that holds a colon. However, using this method this string from the book was recognized as a valid path... (which is obviously wrong)

Answer (score -2):

I think the only invalid character (except control chars) on OSX is the colon - so you simply have to test if the new filename contains colons.

Comment: bad advice. What abut, for one, "/"?

Comment: Note that “/” is a valid character in macOS filenames.